# OS X Mavericks Maps: can't send direction to iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, maps

First of all, **I have solved the problem**. It took me quite a while to figure out, so I'll share the solution here in case anyone runs into the same problem.

To put it short, you should be able to see a "Send to $NAME_OF_YOUR_IPHONE" entry in the share menu of Maps.app. If you don't, then **turn on "Documents & Data" in OS X's iCloud settings (System Settings-->iCloud)**. If you want more context, read on.

First you need to make sure you Mac is running OS X 10.9 (which is sheer nonsense, how would you have Maps.app otherwise); your iPhone is running iOS 7 (I guess most iPhones do); and your Mac and iPhone are signed into the same iCloud account. If you do, and you don't get the right share entry, then don't try to sign out iCloud on your Mac, as some people suggested. I've tried it myself and it does not work for me. The problem is that, I'm not a big fan of mobile devices, so I usually have the "Documents & Data" sync option off; as soon as I signed out and signed in again, I turned off "Documents & Data", so nothing happened. Only when I turned it on and relaunched Maps.app did I begin to see my iPhone on my Mac.

So, that is my trick and it worked here. I'm not sure whether it would work for others, so if you tried my trick and nothing happened, please don't complain to me. Thanks.

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question, but you need to put the question part in the question, and then submit the answer as an answer.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is also its own answer.

Comment: I am posting this answer so that the question will not remain listed as an unanswered question. For cases like this, it is probably preferable that the question is posted as a question, and then immediately answered by the original poster.